# Connecting to a projector with HDMI?

Tags: 13.10, ati, projector

I have a HP Envy M6 with AMD A-10 and AMD Radeon HD 8610G. I have installed the propriety AMD drivers. But I am unable to connect to the projector using HDMI. Nothing happens when I connect to the projector. On opening AMD catalyst I can see the projector option but it does not display on the projector.

Comment: Have you tried the display settings? - look like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/XN5c1.png).

Comment: Almost the same but just having "Built in display" instead of "Laptop".....